# how could I Decrypt the SSIS package XML using T-sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, encryption

when I run this query

```
select  cast(cast(packagedata as varbinary(max)) as xml) as PackageData from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
```

i get a result of XML file but it's encrypted like 
`<EncryptedData xmlns="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"; Type="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"; Salt="Gnk/DB61AQ==" IV="iYcfV0NOGy0="> <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"; /> <CipherData> <CipherValue>/TtgJ46P9L23ZeGt67n+2OZGXoHiGWcUAWE8CdN1Z2aiF40fAg6DfBWGx62RB7Botxr‌​w+f1Jf1CtR10iMLw0iz+VIcbaPFZj5ZfCm3aDeDLbnwXdb7mIdzNtF/5EOjNph/kPz7PxcUlAOUvsLLmj‌​Gtx92EhWL6KpXufKahnRiwLuZLNc</CipherValue> </CipherData> </EncryptedData>`

is there any easy way for decryption using T-SQL?

Comment: I believe you will need to use the API [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.aspx) to decrypt the package. Fixed the link thanks to @Siva's bright eyes

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't find any method for Decrypting the returning XML.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy method to decrypt SSIS package XML.